# publish website used ASP mvc and angular 2

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, angular, typescript, publish

I use angular 2 to develop front end and use Asp MVC (not ASP CORE) for back end...

in normal asp mvc application use this steps to publish app :

1. right click on project
2. select publish on menu
3. select profile name
4. connection ...

and other steps

when I use that steps and upload my website on host website just show default loading message used in

```
"<my-app>Loading...</my-app>"
```

this is my published folder used by default steps :

[image: published asp mvc & angular 2 web application folder and files]

please help me ! and say me steps for publish my web application

tanks

Comment: are you using Azure as a host ?

Comment: no I using Shared web hosting service @JoséQuintoZamora

Comment: Please could you share more information, about console log errors, app code, and so on

Comment: should use "ng build" for build published files ? @JoséQuintoZamora

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, i have faced this problem not long time ago, unfortunately i didnt found alot of information about it but can share some experience.

1. create folder inside solution for build artifacts (`wwwroot` in my case)
2. configure angular cli or whatever you use to build your project to store build artifacts there (in my case in .angular-cli.json file set `"outDir": "PROJECT_PATH_OR_EMPTY_IF_ITS_IN_SAME_FOLDER/wwwroot"`)
3. build angular app (in my case `ng build --prod --output-hashing=none --environment=qa`)

here the problems starts: In .net core you can just configure project to load index.html file from wwwroot folder and everything is fine, but i couldn`t do it in that case (any ideas apreciated)

So...

4. modify default route for mvc app to load only one view (angular itself will take care afterwards)

   routes.MapRoute(
         name: "Default",
         url: "{*url}",
         defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
     );
5. modify layout page - copy all index.html content to _Layout.html (make sure that script tags refers to correct files in wwwroot folder)
6. publish as usual

solution example

[image]

I hope it will help.

Comment: is it angular 1 ?

Comment: how I can run "ng build" in my project ... I see in youtube use terminal in visual code to run "ng build"

Comment: you can use any terminal for that purpose if i understand your question right. I am using standart windows 'cmd'. how are you developing on Angular without terminal by the way?

Comment: when use ng build give this error The "@angular/compiler-cli" package was not properly installed.